# Marginal rate of technical substitution for multi-dimension inputs?

Tags: microeconomics

Suppose I have a vector ***x*** = ($x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$) of inputs. How it is the MRTS($x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$) ?

And which is the relation with the marginal products of inputs 1-5 ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate slightly on what you have tried?

Comment: MRTS is defined as holding output fixed while reducing input $i$ while increasing output $j$ so it is always a pairwise description of manipulating two inputs. But for all production functions this is not always possible. Can we assume that the production function is a smooth, differentiable function of degree 2 in all arguments? Can we assume that it is monotonically increasing in all arguments?  Are you just looking for the definition of the MRTS in a multi-input setting? It is the same as in the two input case, the MRTS(i,j) = MarginalProduct(i)/MarginalProduct(j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
MRTS_{x_{i};x_{j}}=\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{i}}/\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{j}} \qquad \forall i\neq j
\end{equation}